# Filters on Nikon 1 Nikkor VR 10-30mm f/3.5-5.6 PD-Zoom lens supplied with the Nikon 1 J5

Tags: nikon, filters

How are filters used on a Nikon 1 Nikkor VR 10-30mm f/3.5-5.6 PD-Zoom lens with built-in lens cap? Is there any way to use a screw on filter?

Answer (score 1):

The Nikon 1 Nikkor VR 10-30mm f/3.5-5.6 PD-Zoom lens does not support the use of screw on filters.

In addition to the Nikon 1 J5, it was also supplied as the kit lens with other Nikon 1 cameras including the J4 and V3 models. Perhaps there were others as well.

The older 1 Nikkor VR 10-30mm f/3.5-5.6 VR that was supplied with the Nikon 1 V1 and J1 cameras does not have the built-in lens cover and can accept 40.5mm screw in filters. The lens was only available as part of a camera kit. If you wish to purchase one you'll have to find one for sale either used, as a "white box" lens from a retailer who breaks up kits (not likely in the case of a Nikon 1), or find a dealer that still has the entire kit, including J1 or V1 camera, in old stock.